# jquery access a form without the class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form,

```
<form id="form3" name="form3">
  <input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="" >Number</input>
  <button type="button" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, in my submit function, I have to get the form. If I do this

```
var formObj = $(this).closest('form');
```

it will give me the form. However, it will be of type object, the trace returns

```
"formObj:[object Object]"
```

I have to get the form as a type of HTMLFormElement. I can do this with

```
var formForm = document.forms["form3"];
```

Which in a trace gives me

```
"formForm:[object HTMLFormElement]"
```

The problem is, I need to access the formForm, without already knowing that it's name is form3, because I need to access it from within the submit function.

How do I access the form, as a type of HTMLFormElement, from inside the button?

Comment: `$(this).closest('form')[0]` ?

Comment: `var formObj = $(this).closest('form');` will return the form(wrapped by jQuery) if `this` refers to a descendant element

Comment: do you need the dom element reference to the form element

Comment: `<input />` elements are self-closing, no `</input>` needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property `[0]` of a jQuery object is the plain DOM element: `$(selector)[0]` if there is only one. You can continue that logic if there are more - `$(selector)[1]` etc.

However, there are cleaner ways of handling this. [It is not good to use inline js (click here for more).](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F)

[Live demo with better practices (click).](http://jsbin.com/IfeZafuy/1/edit)

**Sample markup:**

```
<form class="foo">
  <button type="button" class="my-submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="bar">
  <button type="button" class="my-submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//get button references
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('my-submit-button');

//for each button, add the click function
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

//the function to fire when clicked.
function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(this.form);
  alert(this.form.className);
}
```

**With jQuery, we could even simplify it to:** [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IfeZafuy/4/edit)

```
$('form > button').click(function() {
  console.log(this.form.className);
});
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work for me.

var formObj = $(this).closest('form');
var formForm = document.forms["form3"];
var formTest = $(this).closest('form')[0];

gives me, with a trace,

"formObj:[object Object]"
"formForm:[object HTMLFormElement]"
"formTest:undefined"

Comment: You solved a different problem I didn't know I had, as well. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the parent form inside any event handler on the input elements inside the form with `this.form`, as in

```
function submit() {
    var the_form = this.form;
}
```

or

```
function submit(event) {
    var the_form = event.target.form;
}
```

note that the form already has a submit() function, so you should use another name

```
<button type="button" onclick="my_submit();">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that "this" wasn't calling what I thought it should have, the button. I solved the problem by changing

```
onclick="my_submit(this);"

function my_submit(btn) {
  var formForm = btn.form;
}
```

And that worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Especially since you are already using jQuery, I really hope you will take my suggestion (see my answer) and not use `onlick` in your html. See the google link my in my answer for more information.